# Firebase Database Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted all the registration to go to the same folder with uid (ex. Users) instead of being scattered. Can you help me?

```
 private void sendUserData (){
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef  = firebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Users");
    StorageReference imageReference = storageReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Images").child("Profile Pic");
    UploadTask uploadTask = imageReference.putFile(imagePath);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're building the path in the database with this:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                              .getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Users");
```

So the path is `/$uid/Users`, while you probably want `/Users/$uid`. To accomplish that, reverse the order:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                              .getReference("Users").child(firebaseAuth.getUid());
```